# Facebook login button's 1000px iframe causes scrollbar flickering

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

My webapp uses a

```
<fb:login-button>
```

which is XFBML (eXtended Facebook Markup Language) and is rendered to:

```
<fb:login-button login_text="" class=" fb_iframe_widget" fb-xfbml-state="parsed" fb-iframe-plugin-query="app_id=[my app ID]&amp;locale=en_US&amp;login_text=%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20&amp;sdk=joey&amp;><span style="vertical-align: top; width: 0px; height: 0px;"><iframe name="f1987cba84" width="1000px" height="1000px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" title="fb:login_button Facebook Social Plugin" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/login_button.php?app_id=[my app ID]&amp;channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D27%23cb%3Df15dab5c84%26domain%3Dmyapp.com%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fmyapp.com%252Ff1e9e1d5b8%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;locale=en_US&amp;login_text=%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20&amp;sdk=joey&amp;size=xlarge" style="border: none; visibility: hidden;"></iframe></span></fb:login-button>"
```

For some reason, the button contains a 1000 x 1000 px iframe.  Of course, this doesn't actually display as 1000 x 1000 pixels on the webpage, but it's enough to confuse all browsers into temporarily displaying a scrollbar while the button is rendering, on page load.

Is there any way to stop this scrollbar flickering, aside from the hack of hiding the scrollbar in CSS using `overflow:hidden` and then setting `document.body.style.overflow = 'visible';` in Javascript once the button is finished rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need a 1000 pixel iframe, you can always just specify a different width using CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/jjordanca/6UEHp/

HTML:

```
<p>Hi.</p>

<iframe width="1000px" height="300px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" title="fb:login_button Facebook Social Plugin" src="http://www.microsoft.com"></iframe>

<p>Bye.</p>
```

CSS:

```
iframe {position: relative; width: 500px;}
```

Notice that the CSS width specification overrides the inline width specification.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could add the following CSS to the parent div (the one with class="fb-like"):

```
width: 48px; height: 20px; overflow: hidden; text-align: left
```